Как правильно: это более чем оправда(н/нн)о?

В недавней теме встретилось мне такое написание: это более чем оправдано.

Н или НН нужно писать в этом случае и почему?

А это практика письма, обратите внимание:

Предложения со словосочетанием «более чем оправданно»
Предложения со словосочетанием «более чем оправдано»
Так как же правильно и главное — почему?

Пожалуй, дополню вопрос еще одним примером по теме:

Это тем более оправдано(н/нн), что в путь отправились только внедорожники.
Ситуация похожая: решения можно найти в Сети, но нет объяснения.

Интересно, кто минусует вопросы-ответы? При этом делает это анонимно.

Можно только догадываться)  Я и то удивляюсь, что не с меня начали, а с вас.

Ответ Грамоты.ру.
Краткие формы прилагательного оправданный (кроме формы мужского рода) пишутся с одной буквой н, если есть дополнение (оправданы важностью проекта), и с двумя н, если дополнения нет (его действия вполне оправданны; ваше беспокойство оправданно). См.: Русский орфографический словарь РАН / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина, О. Е. Ивановой. – 4-е изд., испр. и доп. – М., 2012. Поэтому правильно: цена оправдана качеством, удобством и широким набором функций.

А минусовать-то ответ зачем? Что руководит людьми – трудно сказать.

Серж, меня интересует именно это сочетание (это более чем оправда(н/нн)о?), а правило я знаю. Укажите ваш правильный вариант в начале ответа. И кстати, почему пишут по-разному, какое написание вы считаете частотным? Как-то не доходят до пользователей решения словаря РАН. Надо почаще обращать на эту орфограмму внимание. Почему у нас на форуме принят неверный ответ, где предлагается не доверять решению по словарю.
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/481890/Как-правильно-это-более-чем-оправдан-нно

Sharon, я не знаю, о каком вопросе идет речь. Но в данном случае — прилагательное. Следовательно: решение более чем оправданно.


Русский орфографический словарь

оправданный; кр. ф. прич. -ан, -ана; кр. ф. прил. -ан, -ана (с дополн.: оправданы важностью проекта) и -ан, -анна (без дополн.: его действия вполне оправданны; ваше беспокойство оправданно)
Вы приравниваете более чем к наречию степени вполне для оправданный. Может, тогда надо указать в правилах, что только НАЛИЧИЕ дополнения в Т. п. меняет написание, да?  А вот наречия степени не меняют, ведь это не всем пользователям очевидно, судя по разнообразию их решений.

Хорошо, давайте посмотрим на второе предложение:
№ 203118.
Это тем более оправдаНо (или НН?), что в путь 
отправились только внедорожники.
ответ
Правильно: Это тем более оправданно, что в путь 
отправились...



Это тем более оправданно (тем), что в путь отправились...
Вроде бы указательное слово пропущено в СПП (придаточное изъяснительное), а ведь оно в Т. п.
У меня есть сомнения по поводу правильности этого решения. А если оставить указательное слово, то как писать?

Дело в том, что указательное слово тем не обозначает активного деятеля.  Поэтому два нн.

Серж, чтобы быть причастием, а не прилагательным слову нужен Т. п, обозначающий  лицо или инструмент действия. Это тем более оправда(н/нн)   отправкой в путь только внедорожников. Здесь сколько Н? Или, к примеру  Это тем более отправда (н/нн)о желанием...

А так? Тем более это в какой-то мере оправдано законом. Тем более это в какой-то мере оправдано тем, что закон на их стороне. //   Извините меня за настойчивость) но хочется закрыть тему каким-то определенным выводом. А то у нас получается правописание по стилистике)   А пользователи, кстати, эту орфограмма плохо знают. Помнится, у нас в 2022 году ее тоже никто не знал. Пусть лингвисты имеют в виду)

В примере первом явно два нн. Во втором примере даже при наличии указательного слова тем, вряд ли можно говорить о творительном лице или инструменте.

Нет, не правописание по стилистике. Просто если пример надуман, неясен в смысловом отношении, то не стоит обсуждать правописание.

Вот ненадуманный пример: "Проверяйте, что сделали менеджеры, ежедневно, еженедельно и ежемесячно, да хоть почасово, если это оправдано вашим бизнес-процессом".  Это правильно?

Да. В этом случае два нн.

Это почему же? Стилистика нормальная? Это прилагательное (значение переносное). Зависимое слово в Т. п. есть? Тогда по правилу пишется одно н.

Да, конечно, одна н. Думаю одно, пишу другое.

Спасибо за ответы) Будем считать, что мы наполовину договорились. Интересно услышать ваше мнение по этому вопросу  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/481898/Выбор-Н-или-НН-в-кратком-причастии-по-правилу
