Н или НН в кратком причастии/прилагательном по правилу из Русского орфографического словаря
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
Рассмотрим предложение: Отнесение этого вида к “ранним Homo” оправдано морфологически, но его статус и эволюционное положение пока неясны.
Как здесь применить правило, указанное в Русском орографическом словаре:
оправданный; кр. ф. прич. -ан, -ана; кр. ф. прил. -ан, -ана (с дополн.: оправданы важностью проекта) и -ан, -анна (без дополн.: его действия вполне оправданны; ваше беспокойство оправданно)
Вопрос о наречие морфологически — здесь значение образа действия, но  не степени, как в наречии вполне. Можно заменить: морфологически — морфологией.
Это краткое прилагательное, значение переносное. Как влияет зависимое слово, нужно писать НН или Н?
А это Карта слов:  Предложения со словом «оправдано», где правописание скорее на вкус авторов, но вряд ли по правилу.

Шарон, в том примере также два нн. Не понимаю, в чем сложность для вас и в чем ваши сомнения.

На нашем форуме задавался подобный вопрос, и на него ответил ИРЯ.

Дайте ссылку на вопрос. ИРЯ – это  все же не доказательство абсолютной истины, мне важно, что я сомневаюсь. Я напишу свой ответ. А к ИРЯ все те же претензии – страшно далеки они от народа)  Если есть правило, то пусть посмотрят, как пользователи его применяют. А они его аккуратно обходят  стороной, как нечто несуществующее (см. Карту слов). Согласитесь, что здесь есть определенная недоработка со стороны ИРЯ.

Вот еще задача для ИРЯ:  "Несмотря на недолгий этап её становления, она чрезвычайно насыщенна не только именами, работами, но и событиями, особенно в нашей стране".  Здесь есть наречие степени и дополнение в Т. п.  Карта слов:  https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словом/насыщенна

Шарон, обязательно дам ссылку, как найду. Если не ошибаюсь, вам на почту тоже посылал. Плохо помню вопрос.

Карта слов все же не орфографический словарь. Она служит для проверки грамотности.

См. ответ ИРЯ в новом вопросе на сайте.

Отнесение этого вида к “ранним Homo” оправдано морфологически, но его статус и эволюционное положение пока неясны.

Трудность данной орфограммы заключается в следующем. С одной стороны, мы должны отличить причастие (прямое значение действия, одно Н) от прилагательного с переносным значением). С другой, выбор Н или НН в прилагательном зависит от вида синтаксической конструкции. Другими словами, слова могут вести себя как прилагательные (НН) или как причастия (Н) при наличии дополнения. В то же время по наличию переносного значения их приходится  отличать от причастий с прямым значением действия (одно Н).

В заданном предложение выбор одной Н мне представляется правильным —  чувствуется значение действия, но не признака: Отнесение этого вида к “ранним Homo” оправдывается морфологически, но его статус и эволюционное положение пока неясны.

С другой, стороны чувства у всех разные и доказательством служить не могут. Поэтому нужны формальные признаки для решения, а иначе это приводит к бесконечным разборкам в Сети.

В предложении нет определенности, так как зависимое слово присутствует, но оно не дополнение в Т. п. и не наречие степени. Получается непроявленная зона.

Поэтому НУЖНЫ дополнительные пояснения о том, каким фактором считать наречие морфологически.  К примеру, я преобразовываю предложение и полагаю, что в нем в большей степени проявляется действие, поэтому нужно писать одно Н. А ИРЯ или РАН пусть предлагают свои варианты однозначных решений, все-таки это их работа.



Можно рассмотреть еще одно предложение по теме, где выбор также не регулируется правилом напрямую:
Жизнь моя насыще(н/нн)а до предела.
Пояснение
Здесь есть зависимое слово, но это не дополнение в Т. п. Так как же решается эта задача?
Здесь представляется корректной такая замена: до предела — в полной мере, чрезвычайно. Тогда дополнение усиливает значение качественного признака и соответствует наречию степени, поэтому пишем два НН: Жизнь моя насыщенна до предела.
В то же время такой вариант не выглядит стилистически корректным, так что лучше использовать наречие степени.
Примеры по теме
Жизнь главной героини НАСЫЩЕННА и полна сюрпризов. Это краткое прилагательное с двумя буквами НН, так как нет дополнения (чем?), но есть однородные отношения с другим прилагательным.
Сравнить: Жизнь главной героини НАСЫЩЕНА сюрпризами. Это краткое прилагательное с одной буквой Н, так как есть дополнение (чем?).
И жизнь эта так богата событиями, так насыщенна, что, безусловно, заслуживает отдельного рассказа и самого пристального изучения. Петр Ефимович Люкимсон, Царь Давид
Жизнь современного человека необыкновенно насыщенна.
Ирина Красоткина, Аутотренинги
Мир, в котором внешне не происходит почти ничего, однако внутренняя жизнь здесь насыщенна и интересна. Андрей Максимов, Песталоцци. Воспитатель человечества, 2023
Материал по теме о выборе Н/НН по правилу (не сошлись во мнениях): Орфографические войны

Я бы написала с одной "н", так как это зависимое слово (хоть и не дополнение, но и не наречие меры и степени), но в корпусе много вариантов, где использовано не дополнение. Думается, что творительный падеж для данного правила искусственно придуман:

Жизнь моя насыщена (как, до чего) до предела.

Можем сказать, что это обстоятельство-дополнение, да и в словарной статье "Грамоты" для данного слова тоже указано, что при наличии дополнения пишем "н", но это:
-Раз, не творительный падеж;
-Два, классификация позволяет рассмотреть конструкцию как обстоятельство;
-Три, написание данной конструкции зафиксировано в нормативном словаре.

Я бы написала –нн-. Для меня «оправдано» имеет одно значение, а «оправданно» - другое. С одной –н- я понимаю это слово так: признано невиновным, правым. Также значение «возмещается», как в предложении «Цена оправдана качеством» и значение «признаны извинительными» в примере «оправданы важностью проекта» А с двумя – значение «допустимо, правильно, имеет право на существование». Насчет «морфологически». На мой взгляд, не морфология оправдывает, а нечто является оправданным с точки зрения морфологии. Мое чутье говорит мне, что в данном случае «оправданно»  прилагательное, потому что признак постоянный. Я даже не могу добавить слово «было» в это предложение, потому что оно становится странным.

Я пишу с одной Н.  Это прилагательное, обозначает постоянный признак. В полной форме  – является оправданным. В краткой форме: отнесение  оправданно, но отнесение оправдано  (чем?) морфологией, то есть видовыми признаками. Речь идет не о выборе между причастием и прилагательным, а о том, что прилагательное ведёт себя как причастие, то есть реагирует на синтаксис. Или так: отнесение совершенно оправданно. Я говорю о том, что в правиле не указаны все варианты грамматических признаков, позволяющие однозначно решить задачу, а указан только Т. п. дополнения.
